# What is the proper setup for spark with cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

After using and playing around with the spark connector, I want to utilize it in the most efficient way, for our batch processes.

is the proper approach to set up a spark worker on the same host where Cassandra node is on? does the spark connector ensure data locality?

I am a bit concerned that a memory intensive spark worker will cause the entire machine to stop, then I will lose a Cassandra node, so I'm a bit confused whether I should place the workers on the Cassandra nodes, or separate (which means no data locality). what is the common way and why?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on your particular use case. Some things to be aware of

1) CPU Sharing, while memory will not be shared (heaps will be separate) between Spark and Cassandra. There is nothing stopping spark executors from stealing time on C* cpu cores. This can lead to load and slowdowns in C* if the spark process is very cpu intensive. If it isn't then this isn't much of a problem.

2) Your network speed, if your network is very fast then there is much less value to locality than if you are on a slower network.

So you have to ask yourself, do you want a simpler setup (everything in one place) or do you want a complicated setup but more isolated.

For instance DataStax (the company I work for) ships Spark running colocated with Cassandra by default, but we also offer the option of having it run separately. Most of our users colocate possibly because of this default, those who don't usually do so because of easier scaling.